# Скрипт для создания изображений с одинаковым элементом

Tags: photoshop

Имеется несколько десятков изображений одинакового размера. На них требуется разместить элемент в левом нижнем углу, это другое небольшое изображение. Как можно автоматизировать добавление этого элемента и сохранение новой картинки, чтобы не работать с каждым изображением по отдельности?

Comment: Объяснять долго, копировать лениво. Гугли на "photoshop watermark batch".